# How do I SSH tunnel using PuTTY or SecureCRT through gateway/proxy to development server?

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, putty, tunneling

We have some unix boxes setup in a way that to get to the development box via ssh, you have to ssh into a 'user@jumpoff' box first. There is no direct connection allowed on 'dev' via ssh from anywhere but 'jumpoff'. Furthermore, only key exchange is allowed on both servers. And you always login to the development box as 'build@dev'.

It's painful to always do that hopping. I know this can be done with SOCKS or a Tunnel or something...

I have setup a FreeBSD VM and I can get things to work awesome using unix ssh tools. Basically all I do is make sure my vm's ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub key is on both jumpoff and dev and use this ~/.ssh/config file:

```
# Development Server
Host            ext-dev  # this must be a resolvable name for "dev" from Jumpoff
Hostname        1.2.3.4
User            build
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa  

# The Jumpoff Server
Host            ext 
Hostname        1.1.1.1
User            daevid
Port            22 
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# This must come below all of the above 
Host            ext-* 
ProxyCommand    ssh ext nc $(echo '%h'|cut -d- -f2-) 22
```

Then I just simply type "ssh ext-dev" and I'm in like Flynn.

The problem is I can't get this same thing to work using either PuTTY or SecureCRT -- and to be honest I've not found any tutorials that really walk me through it. I see many on setting up some kind of proxy tunnel for Firefox, but it doesn't seem to be the same concept. I've been messing with various trial and error most all day and nothing has worked (obviously) and I'm at the end of my ssh knowledge and Google searching.

I found this link which seemed to be perfect, but it doesn't work for me. The "Master" connects fine, but the "client" portion doesn't connect. It tells me, the remote system refused the connection.
http://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/socksproxy.html

I've got the VM, PuTTY and SecureCRT all using the same public/private key pairs to make things consistent and easier to debug.

Does anyone have a straight up example of how to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Using a fairly recent version of SecureCRT (I'm running 7.3.7 for this example), here is how you do it:

1.) Set up a new connection to your jump-off server (ext) with the IP address 1.1.1.1, as given in your example. Give the connection a name, "Jump-off server", and save it in your Sessions folder.

2.) Test that you can connect to the jump-off server as desired. You have indicated that only access with an SSH key is possible: You might want to import that key using ssh-agent functionality (use the "Tools" menu > "Manage Agent Keys..." > "Add...") if you want to enter your passphrase just once.

3.) Set up a new connection for your dev box. As with step 1.), use the correct IP address - 1.2.3.4, as given in your example - and name it "Development box". Save this session in your Sessions folder. Test this connection: It *should* fail at this point, because you're connecting directly. Close the window.

Now you have the raw information needed, but one extra step is required, to associate the jump-off box as the connection needs to go through "Jump-off box" in order to connect to "Development box".

4.) Right-click on the "Development box" connection in your Sessions folder, and select "Properties". Go to "Connection" -> "SSH2" and click on the "Firewall:" drop-down option. Click on "Select Session...", and then pick "Jump-off server" from the Sessions menu, and then click "OK" to accept the value, then "OK" again to exit the properties menu.

This now associates your jump-off box with your development box, so it is used as an intermediary when trying to establish a connection to your development box. It even works if you have a different SSH port in use on your jump-off box (e.g. 65000) versus your development box (e.g. 22), because SecureCRT will simply use the configuration you have set up for each host.

Try the "Development box" connection again, with or without a "Jump-off box" connection open, and you should find it works as you wanted.

Comment: Sir, this is an excellent answer. I never noticed that you could use any session as firewall in SecureCRT. You have my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

It does seem that PuTTY version 0.59 and later supports ProxyCommand-like syntax; see, for example, [this blog post](http://monkeyswithbuttons.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/ssh-proxycommand-and-putty/). You most likely don't want to use SOCKS. You want to be careful about having strong passphrases for your keys; it's not clear from your OpenSSH example whether you have any passphrase on your key or whether you're using ssh-agent or the like.

Comment: That link is perfect! That seems to do exactly what I wanted without the BS of having extra shells open and a two step process... now if only someone would make a SecureCRT version that does the same thing... hint hint... :)

Answer (score 2):

With PuTTY, make sure you have "agent forwarding" enabled, and your private key loaded in Pageant.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested in doing this with SecureCRT, here it is:

1. Create a SSH session as usual.
2. In properties, select Port Forwarding and click Add..., make sure to check "Dynamic forwarding using SOCKS 4 or 5" option, fill the local address and port accordingly.
3. Done. From now on, each time you ssh with this session config, a tunnel is created automatically, when you disconnect, the tunnel's gone. Pretty much the same as in a Linux box.

Enjoy!